# How to access state from a react function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Basically I am using react-router(version 5) to pass data, however I can't access the state that I passed. Here is the code where it routes from:

```
export default function MarketsList(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  function changePage(sym, id) {
    history.push({ pathname: `/${sym}`, state: { id: id } })
  }
```

how do I access it from the other page? I tried this.state.id but it doesn't work.
here is the code for the other page just in case.

```
export default function Symgraph(props) {
  useEffect(() => {

  }, []);
  const { sym} = useParams();
  return (
    <div className='main-chart mb15' >
      <ThemeConsumer>
        {({ data }) => {
          return data.theme === 'light' ? (
            <AdvancedChart
              widgetProps={{
                theme: 'light',
                symbol: 'OKBUSDT',
                allow_symbol_change: false,
                toolbar_bg: '#fff',
                height: 550,
                details: 'true',
                style: '3',
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            <AdvancedChart
              widgetProps={{
                theme: 'dark',
                symbol: 'OKBUSDT',
                allow_symbol_change: false,
                toolbar_bg: '#000',
                height: 550,
                details: 'true',
                style: '3',
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      </ThemeConsumer>

      <h1>{sym},{this.state.id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: oh it actually does! useLocation works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use useHistory for it

sth like this:

```
  let history = useHistory();

history.location?.state?.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router';
const Component = ()=>{
 const location = useLocation();
 console.log(location.state.id);  // here you can access id;
}
```